# Calculated Column IF/AND question

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

What did I do wrong?

I need a calculated column to return the following:

- If [Status] equals "Pre-OPEN" then return [Date Opened]+3
- If [Status] equals "OPEN" then return [Date Opened]+30
- If [Status] equals "PENDING" then return [Date Opened]+30
- If [Status] equals "REFERRAL" and [Dispo] equals "Active" then return [Date Opened] +5
- If [Status] equals "Pre-OPEN" and [Dispo] equals "Active" then return [Date Opened]+3

  ```
  =IF([Status]="Pre-OPEN",[Date Opened]+3,IF([Status]="OPEN",[Date of Last ROI]+30,IF([Status]="PENDING",[Date of Last ROI]+30,IF(AND([Status]="REFERRAL",[Dispo]=”Active”,[Date Opened]+5,IF(AND([Status]="ONLY",[Dispo]=”Active”,[Date Opened]+10, "")))))
  ```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing **AND** condition close and you need to close it with additional `)` as the following

```
AND([Status]="REFERRAL",[Dispo]="Active")
```

**So the formula should be**

```
=

IF([Status]="Pre-OPEN",[Date Opened]+3,

IF([Status]="OPEN",[Date of Last ROI]+30,

IF([Status]="PENDING",[Date of Last ROI]+30,

IF(AND([Status]="REFERRAL",[Dispo]="Active"),[Date Opened]+5,

IF(AND([Status]="ONLY",[Dispo]="Active"),[Date Opened]+10, "")))))
```